# What are the steps involved in publishing provider hosted apps to SharePoint store/Office store/App marketplace?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

Auto-hosted apps are not supported by Microsoft from next month, June 2014 onwards, Microsoft is recommending auto hosted apps to be converted to provider hosted apps. Publishing a SharePoint hosted app is relatively simpler as it is web scoped and all components are included in .app package.

What are the steps involved in publishing provider hosted apps to SharePoint store/Office store/App marketplace?

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:** Deploy the web application, it could be Azure/own private cloud or hosting infrastructure.

**Step 2:** Package the App

**Step 3:** Publish your app for SharePoint on the Office Store and for that you need to sign in to [your Microsoft Seller Dashboard account.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn188471.aspx)

**Step 4 and on-wards:** In order to publish app to Office Store you need to generate Client IDs and Secrets in the Microsoft Seller Dashboard and [publish it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj552465.aspx) for formal approval

I have put together a small tutorial in a video on SP24 conference site, to publish provider-hosted apps in Azure. Let me know if you have questions:

SP24 conference site: https://www.sp24conf.com/2014-1/Conf/SP24S028/ConfPages/SessionRoom.aspx

Comment: The SP24 conference site link does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Start here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220037(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220037%28v=office.15%29.aspx) (I'm on my phone so can not post and abstract from the link)

See specifically the part about publishing from Visual Studio, get client id and submit SharePoint app to the store